# $w(x,y)=f(x, y, g(x, y))$ where $f$, $g$ are both differentiable. How to find partial derivative.

Tags: calculus

I believe using the chain rule we should get $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, although I'm worried this answer is too simple and there is more to the problem.

Comment: That's not the chain rule.  Write down the general chain rule and then carefully apply it to your problem.  Math is not a guessing game.  Don't guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w(x,y) = f(\hat{x}(x,y),\hat{y}(x,y),\hat{z}(x,y))$, we have:
$$ w_x = f_1 \hat{x}_x + f_2 \hat{y}_x + f_3 \hat{z}_x $$

where $f_1$ is the derivative of $f$ in the first entry, $f_2$ in the second and $f_3$ in the last. We have $\hat{x}(x,y) = x$, $\hat{y}(x,y) = y$ and $\hat{z}(x,y) = g(x,y)$. Then:
$$ w_x = f_1 + f_3 g_x $$